# how to populate combobox in a usercontrol from an array in a class

Tags: vb.net, combobox, user-controls

I have a program in vb.net with a class and an usercontrol with a combobox. I want to populate the combobox with an array in the class. If user selects a value in combobox in usercontrol and return that value into class. I tried lot but there is no use. 
Is it possible? If yes, then please guide me how to do it.

I have written the code for usercontrol as container1 as follows:

```
Private Sub container1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each i As Double In yl
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

ERROR: Name yl is not declared.

yl is an array in my main class in the program.

thanks in advance

gvg

Comment: You can use `Usercontrol` as a class.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. please explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can do this in four steps:

- Create a custom event in the usercontrol that fires when the selectedindex in the combobox is changed
- Create a function that populates the combobox
- Create a readonly property in your class that returns the items for the combobox
- Mix this all together in the base form

First add some functionality to your userform

```
Public Class CtrlBox
'This is a usercontrol, created in VS
'The designer is not shown in this example

'This event is used to relay changes to the combobox to the outside world
Public Event ComboboxSelectionChanged(ByVal NewIndex As Integer, ByVal NewText As String)

'This Sub sets the combobox items
Public Sub SetComboboxItems(Newitems() As String)
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(Newitems)
End Sub

'Here the custom event is raised
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    RaiseEvent ComboboxSelectionChanged(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex, Me.ComboBox1.Items(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString)
End Sub
End Class
```

The class that will contain the selected index is called clsStuff. Notice the readonly property I use to return the desired items in the combobox

```
Public Class clsStuff

'This is like a constant that returns the items you
'want to add to the combobox
Public ReadOnly Property CustomComboItems As String()
    Get
        Return {"Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4"}
    End Get
End Property

'This variable shall store the selected string
Public SomeString As String = ""
End Class
```

Then bring it all together in your main form

```
Public Class Form1
'Drag the usercontrol containing the combobox onto your form

'This object is the one used to populate the combobox
'and store the selected item
Dim StuffObj As clsStuff

'Here the object is initialized and the CB-Items are set
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    StuffObj = New clsStuff
    Me.CtrlBox1.SetComboboxItems(StuffObj.CustomComboItems)
End Sub

'Here the custom event is handled and used to change the
'string in the object
Private Sub CtrlBox1_ComboboxSelectionChanged(NewIndex As Integer, NewText As String) Handles CtrlBox1.ComboboxSelectionChanged
    If StuffObj IsNot Nothing Then
        StuffObj.SomeString = NewText
        MsgBox("Updated property in object: " & StuffObj.SomeString)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

This scheme should work well for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good way to access main program variable from the UserControl, although there is `Parent` property.

**(1)**, you should create a `AddItems()` method to add the items as follow in your UserControl.

```
Public Sub AddItems(ByVal yl As String())
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each i As String In yl
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

**(2)**, create a `SelectedText()` read-only property as follow

```
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedText()
    Get
        Return ComboBox1.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

**(3)**, create an event `SelectedIndexChanged`

```
Public Event SelectedIndexChanged()
```

**(4)**, fire the event

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    RaiseEvent SelectedIndexChanged()
End Sub
```

---

**(5)**, you can add items in your main form like this

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim yl() As String = {"Aa", "Bb", "Cc"}
    Container1.AddItems(yl)
End Sub
```

**(6)**, you can catch `SelectedIndexChanged()` event in your main form

```
Private Sub Container1_SelectedIndexChanged() Handles Container1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.Text = Container1.SelectedText

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt replies. i want a doubt in 5 & 6 is it container1 or combobox1. please clarify.

Comment: it is a `Container1.SelectedText` ... `SelectedText` property is defined in **(2)**

Comment: thank you for your prompt replies. i am using container as usercontrol. there is no form in the main class. when insert the 5 & 6  steps in main class it is saying that" Even load cannot be found".  please clarify.

Comment: if you are using from the `Class`, use `Sub New()` for the `Form_Load()`